# Polymer element not showing in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, polymer, web-component

I've written custom polymer element which works perfect in Chrome. But it's not even showing up in Firefox. I've use vulcanize to concatenate everything in one file even the platform and polymer. This is the main index file which I call for vulcanize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/my_polymer/index.html">
 </head>
</html>
```

This is my polymer element index file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
   <link rel="import" href="my-polymer-element.html">
  </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: I also had an issue with Polymer in Firefox. Did you check the error console?

Comment: There is no warning or error in Chrome but in Firefox I got this warning. mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

Comment: I'm not sure is this error due to Firefox not supporting as I can't even see this page http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/demo.html in Firefox version 31, but at least it shows error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is wrong.

You should not be importing index.html, but instead, import your element definitions in the main page. Your main page should look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
   <link rel="import" href="my-polymer-element.html">
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Note that polymer.html is listed as a dependency import at the top of your `my-polymer-element.html` definition file.

See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html#createpolyel and also the seed-element: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/reusableelements.html for examples.